# Is $\gamma_\mu \gamma^\mu$ a unit operator?

Tags: dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Is the term:

$$γ^μ γ_μ$$
An identity matrix? Since,if we start with both the Dirac equation,
$$(iγ^μ ∂_μ-m)Ѱ=0$$
We find that,
$$iγ^μ ∂_μ=m$$
If we square both sides, we get,
$$-γ^μ γ_μ∂^μ ∂_μ=m^{2}$$
Therefore,
$$-γ^μ γ_μ ∂^μ ∂_μ-m^2=0$$
$$γ^μ γ_μ ∂^μ ∂_μ+m^2=0$$
This situation above resembles the Klein-Gordon equation, solely as an operator, as seen below,
$$(\Box+m^2 )=0$$
Were $\Box$ denotes the d'Alembert operator.

Therefore,
$$γ^μ γ_μ ∂^μ ∂_μ+m^2=(\Box+m^2 )$$

Therefore,
$$γ^μ γ_μ ∂^μ ∂_μ=\Box$$
Since the d'Alembert operator, is defined as 
$$\Box=∂^μ ∂_μ$$
The only way for the above equation to be true is if, 
$$γ^μ γ_μ $$
equals an identity matrix?

Is my reasoning correct, if it isn't then what is the flaw?

Comment: In an eigenvalue problem $A\mathbf x=\lambda\mathbf x\to (A-\lambda I)\mathbf x=0$ does this necessarily mean that $A-\lambda I=0$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Miscellaneous_identities

Comment: There is a conventional explicit choice for the four gamma matrices. You could have tried computing $\gamma^\mu\gamma_\mu$ straightforwardly by matrix multiplication, addition, and subtraction, and discovered that it is *not* the identity matrix (so you would have realized that you must have made a mistake somewhere). However, it turns out that it is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using $\mu$ as an index too many times. When you square $\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$, you have to use a different index for the two factors. Here is a correct derivation:

Starting with $(i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \psi = 0$, apply $-(i \gamma^\nu \partial_\nu + m)$ from the left:
$$ 0 = -(i \gamma^\nu \partial_\nu + m)(i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \psi = (\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu + m^2) \psi. $$
Now, since $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu = \partial_\nu \partial_\mu$, i.e. it is symmetric, only the symmetric part
$$ \gamma^{(\mu} \gamma^{\nu)} = \frac{\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\}}{2}
= \frac{\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu}{2} $$
will survive:
$$ \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu = \gamma^{(\mu} \gamma^{\nu)} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu. $$
But, the defining feature of the $\gamma$ matrices is that $\gamma^{(\mu} \gamma^{\nu)} = \eta^{\mu\nu}$. So you get
$$ (\eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu + m^2) \psi = 0, $$
i.e.
$$ (\partial^\mu \partial_\mu + m^2) \psi = 0, $$
the Klein-Gordon equation.

---

As for what $\gamma^\mu \gamma_\mu$ is,
$$ \gamma^\mu \gamma_\mu =  \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu} = \gamma^{(\mu} \gamma^{\nu)} \eta_{\mu\nu} = \eta^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\mu\nu} = \delta^\mu_\mu = d = 4 $$
if you are working in a four-dimensional spacetime. Here, they key step is using that $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric.